# Slow ORDER BY with large and small tables

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have one small table (200 rows) and two large tables (200k rows each).

Small table has primary key id and some other fields.

First big table has id field (not a primary key), which are duplicated, but sorted numbers and a matchresult_id field, which are id's from a second big table.

Second big table has a field matchresult_id (primary key) and some other fields.

The query:

```
SELECT big2.*
FROM small_table s1
       INNER JOIN small_table s2 ON s1.id = s2.parent_id
       INNER JOIN big_table1 big1 ON s2.id = big1.id
       INNER JOIN big_table2 big2 ON big1.matchresult_id = big2.matchresult_id
ORDER BY big2.matchresult_id
```

The query takes over 1 second to complete. Without `ORDER BY` it takes 0.003 seconds. How to optimize the query?

Edit: Tables structure (some columns are omitted and names changed for the greater simplicity):

```
CREATE TABLE `small_table` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `catalogue_group_parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 #.. plus many more columns
 PRIMARY KEY (`catalogue_group_id`),
 KEY `idx_catalogue_group_parent_id` (`catalogue_group_parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=147 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `big_table1` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `matchresult_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `catalogue_group2item_primary` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 KEY `idx_catalogue_group2item_groupid` (`id`),
 KEY `idx_catalogue_group2item` (`id`,`matchresult_id`),
 KEY `idx_catalogue_group2item_matchresultid` (`matchresult_id`),
 KEY `catalogue_id` (`id`,`matchresult_id`,`catalogue_group2item_primary`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `big_table2` (
 `matchresult_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `matchresult_datecreated` datetime NOT NULL,
 `matchresult_datemodified` datetime NOT NULL,
  #.. plus many more columns
 PRIMARY KEY (`matchresult_id`),
 KEY `match_id` (`match_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=214477 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Welcome to the site? Did you try with **Left Outer Join** in place of **Inner JOIN ** . Because Left Outer Join **return all records from the left table, and the matched records from the right table**. And also try to use the **Group BY** clause.

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN has nothing to do with the query (speed) I'm trying to solve, also GROUP BY? why? I need all results from big2 table.

Comment: @MdHaidarAliKhan Changing the join type will alter the query logic. I doubt it is correct.

Comment: @osemec *The query takes over 1 second to complete. Without ORDER BY it takes 0.003 seconds.* This looks like the optimizer have no enough time for to build correct execution plan, or there is too low memory for sorting. Try to rewrite the FROM section backward (all joins are inner, so the tables order doesn't matter) or to carteszian. I think `small_table (parent_id, id)` will slightly help. And look at the size of sorting buffer - maybe it is not large enough. And add query's EXPLAIN.

Comment: @Akina Writing the query backwards doesn't change the speed.

Comment: Yes, and the chance, that this will help, was small. What about EXPLAIN? And what engines does the tables are built on?

Comment: Please put the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_tables\G` for your tables - it's a great help to figuring out better SQL!

Comment: What are the indexes on big_table2?

Comment: Check the indexes of `small_table`.  Is there no `PRIMARY KEY` in `big_table1`?

Comment: If the Query cache is on, that could explain 0.003s.  Rerun with `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`.

Comment: Some indexes are unnecessary:  When you have `INDEX(a,b)`, you don't also need `INDEX(a)`.

Comment: How many rows in the resultset?